# What is the best way to handle DJANGO migration data with over 500k records for MYSQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, database-migration, django-migrations

- A migration handles creating two new fields `action_duplicate` and `status_duplicate`
- The second migration copies the data from the `action` and `status` fields, to the two newly created fields

```
def remove_foreign_keys_from_user_request(apps, schema_editor):
    UserRequests = apps.get_model("users", "UserRequest")

    for request_initiated in UserRequest.objects.all().select_related("action", "status"):
        request_initiated.action_duplicate = request_initiated.action.name
        request_initiated.status_duplicate = request_initiated.status.name
        request_initiated.save()
```

- The third migration is suppose to remove/delete the old fields `action` and `status`
- The fourth migration should rename the new duplicate fields to the old deleted fields
  The solution here is to remove the dependency on the status and action, to avoid unnecessary data base query, since the status especially will only be `pending` and `completed`

My question is for the second migration. The number of records are between 300k to 600k records so I need to know a more efficient way to do this so it doesn't take up all the memory available.
Note: The Database is `MySQL`.

A trimmed-down version of the `UserRequest` model

```
class UserRequest(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    action_duplicate = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=((ACTION_A, ACTION_A), (ACTION_B, ACTION_B)), default=ACTION_A
    )
    status = models.ForeignKey(ProcessingStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_duplicate = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=((PENDING, PENDING), (PROCESSED, PROCESSED)),
        default=PENDING,
    )
```

Comment: Can yyou share your `UserRequests` model together with the models referred to by `Action` and `Status`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, but this is a trimmed-down version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), and do the update in bulk:

```
def remove_foreign_keys_from_user_request(apps, schema_editor):
    UserRequests = apps.get_model('users', 'UserRequests')
    Action = apps.get_user('users', 'Action')
    Status = apps.get_user('users', 'ProcessingStatus')
    UserRequests.objects.update(
        action_duplicate=Subquery(
            Action.objects.filter(
                pk=OuterRef('action_id')
            ).values('name')[:1]
        ),
        status_duplicate=Subquery(
            Status.objects.filter(
                pk=OuterRef('status_id')
            ).values('name')[:1]
        )
    )
```

That being said, it looks that what you are doing is actually the *opposite* of [*database normalization* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): usually if there is duplicated data, you make an extra model where you make one `Action`/`Status` per value, and thus prevent having the same value for `action_duplicate`/`status_duplicate` multiple times in the database: this will make the database larger, and harder to maintain.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `UserRequest` instead of <s>`UserRequests`</s>.